# how to add an jquery action after window.location

Tags: jquery, window.location

I have this code:

```
jQuery('li.exhibitor-inquery a').click(function( event ) {
   window.location = '/#inquiry-trigger';
   event.preventDefault();

   jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery('#inquiry-trigger').offset().top
      }, 500);

   jQuery('.textwidget .wpcf7').slideToggle('slow');
   jQuery('#inquiry-trigger i').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up', 200);
});
```

Right now if the `li.exhibitor-inquery a` is clicked while on the homepage, it scrolls to the form and opens the form up.  But if on another page, this only goes to the homepage and jumps form, it doesn't scroll to or open it up.

So how can I add an action after the `window.location`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery('li.exhibitor-inquery a').click(function( event ) {
   window.location.href = 'http://'+window.host+'#inquiry-trigger';
 // I assume #inquiry-trigger is on home page, you can set the page in third string otherwise.
   event.preventDefault();

   jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery('#inquiry-trigger').offset().top
      }, 500);

   jQuery('.textwidget .wpcf7').slideToggle('slow');
   jQuery('#inquiry-trigger i').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up', 200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but no good, just does the same thing as the code above if I put the site URL in the +window.host+, if I leave the +window.host+ it open to an undefined page.

Comment: @user1936794 can you share a fiddle of the same?